# How do I prove $\lVert{x}\rVert_2\leq{1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

### If $x^Ty\leq1$ for all $y$ with $\lVert{y}\rVert_2=1$, then $\lVert{x}\rVert_2\leq{1}$. $x,y\in R^n$

I have tried to prove it by using the definition of vector inner product: $$x^Ty=\lVert{x}\rVert_2\lVert{y}\rVert_2cos\theta$$ But this definition is generally used in a space whose dimension is equal to or less than 3, so a better proof is required here.

Comment: Are you guys satisfied with the improvement of my question? : )

Comment: Why is this question still "on hold" ? I have improved it as required.

Comment: The body of the Question should be as self-contained as possible, not relying on the title to bear the burden of posing the problem.  What you wrote as the "definition" of vector inner product is really a geometric interpretation, relating the scalar value of the inner product to an angle of incidence between the (nonzero) vectors $x,y$.  An algebraic definition of inner product can be found in your textbook or on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Algebraic_definition).

Comment: Hardmath,thanks for your comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint** Set $$y =\frac{x}{\| x\|_2}$$

Comment: Cool ! I like your solution, which is so elegant!